# Argmax over vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to write as clean and efficient an expression as possible in order to solve the following problem. I have a set `[[v11,...,v1n],...,[vm1,...,vmn]]` of vectors (stored as an `(m,n,a)` array) and a second set `[b1,...,bk]` (again, as a `(k,a)` array). What I want is `argmax_j dot(vij, bx)` for all `i,x`. I have the following for now, which creates unnecessarily large arrays of which I then have to take the diagonal.

```py
gamma = [[v11,...,v1n],...,[vm1,...,vmn]]  # coordinates (i,j,s)
b = [b1,...,bk]  # coordinates (k,s)

# compute argmaxes
argmaxes = (
    np.tensordot(gamma, b, axes=[[2], [1]])  # coordinates (i,j,k)
    .argmax(axis=1)  # coordinates (i,k)
)

result = np.diagonal(
    np.take(gamma, argmaxes, axis=1),  # coordinates (i, i, k, s)
    axis1=0, axis2=1
)  # coordinates (i, k, s)
```

Is there a way to avoid this step with `np.take` that gives me a ton of redundant information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to accomplish this.

Sidenote, `np.tensordot` might be overkill when `np.inner` can do the job too:

```
import numpy as np

M, N, A = 3, 5, 4
K = 6

gamma = np.random.rand(M, N, A)
b = np.random.rand(K, A)

argmaxes = np.inner(gamma, b).argmax(axis=1) # (M, K)

result = gamma[np.arange(M)[:, None], argmaxes] # (M, K, A)
```

Alternatively, via `np.take_along_axis`:

```
result = np.take_along_axis(gamma, argmaxes[:, :, None], axis=1)
```

Also note that in your example implementation, `np.diagonal` inserts the new dimension at the end. The above differs from your code only with a transpose.